# Error when entering bower install angular-gridster

Tags: angularjs, git, github, bower, bower-install

When I hit the command in my terminal:

```
bower install angular-gridster
```

I receive the following error:

```
bower ECMDERR
Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize.git", 
exit code of #128 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Additional error details:
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

Here's a link to the repo I want to access: https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster

Do I have to create a bower.json first?
Not familiar with this kind of error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try at least using https instead of git protocol (as in [bower issue 102](https://github.com/Hacklone/private-bower/issues/102)):

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

If `telnet github.com 9418` does not work, it would mean the git protocol (which uses port 9418) would not be able to access GitHub.

Clearing the cache ([issue 50](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/50#issuecomment-37408959)) can help too (on Windows: `C:\user<user>\AppData\Roaming\bower\cache`). Or `bower cache clean`.

You can also permanently change the url:

```
bower i https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster.git --save
```

Comment: You know, the problem is still unknown, but after I waited 10 minutes and wrote the same command prompt, it worked. Maybe there was still some initializing events in the background still working?

Comment: @KunalOjha Still, trying https instead of git is safer.